# Placing a div below another div using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have markup like so:

HTML:

```
<ListElementRoot>
  <ListElementText>
    {children}
  </ListElementText>
  <ListElementDescription>
    {description}
  </ListElementDescription>
</ListElementRoot>
```

//platform.web.js

```
export const ListElementRoot = div(style.root)
export const ListElementIcon = div(style.icon)
export const ListElementText = div(style.text)
export const ListElementDescription = div(style.description)
```

//CSS

```
.root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-gray2);
  padding: 0;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.text {
  color: #000;
  font-size: calc(var(--font-size-body) / 10)rem;
  padding-left: 64px;
}

.description {
  color: #000;
  font-size: calc(var(--font-size-body) / 12.3)rem;
  padding-left: 64px;
}
```

I'm new to flexbox. 
How can I make  element just under ?

I'm trying to find a solution but it is heavily twisted in flexbox for me (for now). Any ideas?

EDIT:

Without flex-direction: column;

[image]

**With** flex-direction: column;

[image]

Comment: Since absolute positioning work inconsistent cross browsers, where is the `icon` in the markup, and its `align-items: center;` is suppose to be on the container, not flex item, so does it container something you need to center horizontal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a `flex-direction` property set to `column` for your `flex` container (`.root`).

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ho41wwr3/1/) you can find a jsfiddle example.

**EDIT**:
Change `align-items: center` to be `align-items: flex-start` in order to have the elements align to the left